# Please help me to understand java structure

Tags: java

```
public class MyDate {
    private int day = 1;
    private int month = 1;
    private int year = 2000;

    public MyDate(int day, int month, int year) 
    {
        this.day = day;
        this.month = month;
        this.year = year;
    }

    public MyDate(MyDate date) 
    {
        this.day = date.day;
        this.month = date.month;
        this.year = date.year;
    }

    /*
        here why do we need to use Class name before the method name?
    */
    public MyDate addDays(int moreDays) 
    {
        // "this" is referring to which object and why?
        MyDate newDate = new MyDate(this);
        newDate.day = newDate.day + moreDays;

        // Not Yet Implemented: wrap around code...
        return newDate;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return "" + day + "-" + month + "-" + year;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please try to read the basics of java like method signature and about this keyword.

Comment: Seems to be MyDate is immutable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` will refer to the current object instance that you will create. Inside any java methods, `this` will always hold a reference to its object instance.

An example -

```
MyDate myDate = new MyDate(10, 10, 2012);
myDate.addDays(10);
```

The line that you were wondering about will point to the `newDate` object that is created here. The line -

```
MyDate newDate = new MyDate(this);
```

will use this constructor -

```
public MyDate(MyDate date) {
    this.day = date.day;
    this.month = date.month;
    this.year = date.year;
}
```

to create and return a new object, passing it a reference to the current object instance, so that it can copy its day, month and year values.

Answer (score 2):

Answer for 1.
using Class name before the method name means that you are going to return reference variable of type MyDate.Its just a return type.

Answer for 2.
this refers to the current object that is your MyDate class object.
In order to create an new object with 'new' keyword you can use 'this' as a shortcut.But the 'this' should be found inside your class for which you are trying to reference an object.

Answer (score 0):

`here why do we need to use Class name before the method name.`

because this is a method which is returning a reference of type `MyDate`

`"this" is referring to which object and why?`

[this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html) is referring to the current object

Answer (score 0):

> here why do we need to use Class name before the method name.

You are returning a `MyDate` object, that class name is the return type of the function.

> "this" is referring to which object and why?

`this` always refers to the current object on which the method is called. It looks to be copying the current `MyDate` object into a new one and returning it.